# Event Binding in angular4

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I want to call methods on click event bind click event on ngOnInit() using angular4. My requirement is to bind click event on span which i have done it but when i call my other method using if conditions then gives me the error this.getSellingChats is not a function in console. here is my code

```
ngOnInit() { 

this.scrollToBottom();
this.getallChats();
this.checkConnection();
setTimeout(() => {
    this.bindClickevents();    
}, 3000);

}

bindClickevents(){
$('tabset ul li a').find('span').bind('click',function(event){

    var _tab = $(this).text();
    if(_tab == 'ALL'){
        this.getallChats();
    }
    else if(_tab == 'SELLING'){
        this.getSellingChats();

    }
    else if(_tab == 'BUYING'){
        this.getBuyingChats();
    }
    else if(_tab == 'BLOCKED'){
        this.getBlockedChats();
    }
});
```

}

Basically what i want to achieve is bind click event on span and then user click on different tabs methods called according to if conditions. I don't want to call the following methods in ngOnInit() method.

```
    this.getSellingChats();
    this.getBuyingChats();
    this.getBlockedChats();
```

Please provide me solution. Will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The solution is to read the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding---event-). If you use JQuery to handle user events, there's no point in using Angular.

Comment: Yes i have declared it in my ts file.

Comment: How can achieve event binding using angular4. Help me if you are saying that there is no point using angular. @trichetriche

Comment: I'm not giving you an Angular course over Stack Overflow. I helped you with a direct link on how to handle user clicks in Angular. Now you have to read it.

Comment: I can't bind (click) event because my Html is loading dynamically that's why i am using jquery here to bind click event.

Comment: of course as expected you are here to down vote my question and send me a link. No doubt its useful but i don't have much time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is not the reference of your component inside the `find` method. Try it like following.

```
    bindClickevents(){
    const comp = this;
    $('tabset ul li a').find('span').bind('click',function(event){

        var _tab = $(this).text();
        if(_tab == 'ALL'){
            comp.getallChats();
        }
        else if(_tab == 'SELLING'){
            comp.getSellingChats();

        }
        else if(_tab == 'BUYING'){
            this.getBuyingChats();
        }
        else if(_tab == 'BLOCKED'){
            comp.getBlockedChats();
        }
    });
    }
```